# Magento add tekst to checkout

Tags: magento, text, addition, checkout

I want to add text under the button 'Place Order' in the checkout page. (it's a onepage checkout).

I have searched in

> app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\checkout.xml

and in

> \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout

Can someone please help how to add text under the button place text?

Comment: Thanks! I added text in HTML in div.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple text addition you can see the button in this file and add HTML beneath it:

```
app\design\frontend\[theme]\default\template\checkout\onepage\review\button.phtml
```

Best to make a copy of this file (with the same path structure) in your own theme directory.